# How is this URL modification possible?

Tags: url, html4

Could anyone please tell how the site http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?what.html is working in such way? Modifying the url without loading/reloading the page. I think this is not done by html5. Because it works in IE6 which doesn't support html5.

Comment: It's javascript. You know, you can check the page source with your browser to see how it works. By the way, that site uses HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created that site. The commenter is correct, it uses Javascript to change the URL. There's nothing about how that navigation works that is different for IE6 - that browser supports the necessary client-side functionality to do this kind of thing. The basic functionality involves:

1. capturing click events on the nav, and loading the inner content via AJAX
2. update the URL to reflect a working direct URL to target.

The links also are valid anchor links that, in the absence of Javascript, would go to the same page (but load the whole thing). This is your basic AJAX web site setup with one minor difference. It's common practice to use a URLs like this in AJAX/single page web sites:

```
http://mysite.com/home#somepage
```

or even just

http://mysite.com/#somepage

Where the hashtag part represents the actual page a user has navigated to.  If someone accessed that url directly, e.g. from outside the site, the site would use Javascript to load the correct content based on the hashtag, after the page had loaded. This means that there might be a little delay for the inner content to reflect the correct page, since it has to run another request after the initial page has loaded from the browser to get the inner content via AJAX.

I was trying to avoid that by creating a setup that worked completely with and without Javascript. If you go directly to a URL within the site such as http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?faq.html you will notice it loads the content directly. This URL will work even if Javascript is disabled. You can't actually do this using hashtags, since hashtag content *is not* sent to the server. Only the client knows what's after the hashtag in a URL. That's why I was using query strings to represent inner pages.

This site architecture was sort of an experiment at the time. It works pretty well but the code isn't fantastic, I didn't really do anything else with it, and I'm sure there are other better-fleshed-out/tested/full-featured frameworks out there to do much the same thing.

But it might not be a bad example of the nuts and bolts of creating a basic AJAX navigation setup, as a learning tool, since it's pretty concise, and also does HTML5 history navigation (e.g. so the back button works on modern browsers).

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply @Jamie Treworgy